# ObservableBoolean binding not updating visibility of progress bar

Tags: android, android-databinding

Using `AS 3.2.1` with `targetSdkVersion 28`. I have a `RecyclerView` with items containing a button and a progress bar. The visibility of the progress bar is bound to an [ObservableBoolean](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/ObservableBoolean) with its initial value set to **false**.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:onClick="@{() -> data.onLoad()}" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:visibility="@{data.isLoading ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE}" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

In the button's `onClick` handler I try to make the progress bar visible by setting this value to **true**:

```
public void onLoad() {
    isLoading.set(true);
}
```

Nothing happens. The progress bar stays invisible! However, if I set the *initial* value to **true** the progress bar becomes visible!

**Q:** How can I use data binding to initially hide a view, and then show it? (Please note that all my bindings work, except this visibility toggling.)

---

### UPDATE

Turns out that the following method breaks the two-way binding due to some weird precedence rule (bug) in the data binding framework:

```
public boolean getIsLoading() { return isLoading.get(); }
```

Comment: Did you try without getter and setter, just use public `isLoading`.

Comment: Then it works. The problem is that the binding framework silently picks the getter, resulting in hard-to-find UI bugs. I have reported this to google.

Comment: Yes, it seems a bug, did you try naming only `loading` instead of `isLoading`? does that make difference?